# trying to compile Appengine project on a SunOs uxb 5.10 sparc V210 Solaris appengine-api-1.0-sdk version

Tags: google-app-engine

trying to compile Appengine project on a SunOs uxb 5.10 sparc V210 Solaris

I get the following error message:

```
    guestbook/BT.java:4: cannot access com.google.appengine.api.backends.BackendService
    bad class file: /home/mflll/Guestbook/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.0.jar(com/google/appengine/api/backends/BackendService.class)
    class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
    import com.google.appengine.api.backends.BackendService;
                                             ^
    1 error
```

This was with the Solaris Sparc (SVR4 pafckage) jdk-7u45-solaris-sparc.tar.Z
from Oracle Java SE Development Kit 7u45 (under Java SE downloads)

I tried appengine-java-sdk-1.8.0.zip on the google 
Appengine section in code.google.com
Same error message.

Dr. Laurence Leff  Associate Professor of Computer Science,
Western Illinois University, Macomb IL 61455  on sabbatical

Answer (score 0):

Class file version 50 is jdk6, while version 49 is jdk5. It means that you are trying to run class compiled to Java6 on Java5 JVM. Best to check your configuration via `java -version`.